# Less - Mixin a class that is attached to a parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

For some context, I am using [bootstrap nav pills](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) as triggers for [bootstrap collapsibles](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

This is what bootstraps less for nav pills looks like (simplified)

```
.nav-pills {
  > li {    
    // Active state
    &.active > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-color;
        background-color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-bg;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a collapsible is collapsed, it adds a `collapsed` class to the trigger (the `.nav-pills > li` element in this case). What I am trying to do, is simply apply the `.active` class to the nav pill when it doesn't have the class `.collapsed`.

I tried to do

```
:not(.collapsed) { .active; }
:not(.collapsed) { &:extend(.active); }
:not(.collapsed) { &:extend(.active all); }
```

But none of them would yield the results I wanted. The first one wouldn't even compile.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I understand it you need something like: `li:not(.collapsed) { &:extend(li.active all); }` (or `.nav-pills > li` at both sides instead of just `li` if  you need it to be more specific). Note that `extend` searches for an exactly matching selectors starting at the very top level (i.e. `extend(.active);` won't find `.active` *inside* `.nav-pills > li.active`), countrary `extend(.active all)` will match *any* selector with `.active` element hence it injects itself into *every* selector where `.active` appears (and it's one or two hundreds of such selectors in Bootstrap).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That comment is very worthy of being an answer. I think you should post it as one.

Comment: @Harry, yep, sorry, I just did not expect the comment to be that wide when I started to write it :) (and then did not bother to consider if it could be an answer becase of the lack of any feedback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

```
@import (reference) "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

.nav-pills {
  > li > a:not(.collapsed) {
  &:extend(.nav-pills > li.active > a all);
}
}
```

outputs:

```
.nav-pills > li > a:not(.collapsed),
.nav-pills > li > a:not(.collapsed):hover,
.nav-pills > li > a:not(.collapsed):focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

It seems that  `a:not(.collapsed)` not matches `a` without a `class` atribute so you so initiate your HTML with `class="collapsed"`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tabs" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tabs" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tabs" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**end update**

I'm not sure if i understand your question well. I think you could possible use the [collapse events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) and jQuery:

```
$('#tabs').on('show.bs.collapse', function (event) 
{
  $('[href="#' + $(event.target).attr('id') + '"]').parent().addClass('active'); 
});
$('#tabs').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (event) 
{
  $('[href="#' + $(event.target).attr('id') + '"]').parent().removeClass('active'); 
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/WvpaNi4LlZ

Comment: Perfect. The only thing I had to change was that the `:not(.collapsed)` selector had to go on the `li` and not the `a`.